# Directive callback executed after ng-if removes directive from scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, callback, angularjs-scope

- I have an angular directive on my page, within ng-if.
- I have a service which exposes a function that receives a callback as a parameter. Let's call this function functionX.

When the ng-if expression evaluates to true, my directive invokes functionX, and sends it a callback to execute at some point in the future.

Now, the problem is: If my ng-if expressions now changes to false, the service still executes the callback I sent it...

Any ideas how to deal with this issue?

Comment: please paste some of your code, so that we can help you.

Comment: I've figured out what was causing the callback to execute after the directive's scope was destroyed by ng-if evaluating to false: The service was registering the directive scope to a PubSub publish event, and not de-registering it once the directive scope was destroyed. Which means that there was a reference to the destroyed scope hanging on out there... So in summary: Always make sure to clean up after yourself when registering for PubSub events!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out what was causing the callback to execute after the directive's scope was destroyed by ng-if evaluating to false:

The service was registering the directive scope to a PubSub publish event, and not de-registering it once the directive scope was destroyed. Which means that there was a reference to the destroyed scope hanging on out there...

So in summary: Always make sure to clean up after yourself when registering for PubSub events!

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap functionX in a promise and use the .then() method on the resolved promise to execute what was previously the callback function?

This would allow you to execute within the directive, rather than within the service.

I guess it depends what the functions are doing, but sounds like this could be a potential solution.

Comment: Tx @iangregson ! My issue with this solution is that the .then will only execute functionX once, whereas with the callback, it executed each time it was triggered in the service. Any other ideas? Also, why, once the ngIf evaluates to false, is there still an instance of its scope hanging around with the callback func on it? Tx again!

Comment: I'm afraid I can't think of any other ideas off the bat - if you post up some code and the what you're trying to achieve with the code maybe we could get further. On the second point, I remember the docs on ngIf saying the element would be removed from the DOM as opposed to hidden (like ngHide does) but I don't remember it guaranteeing that everything would get removed from execution context. I haven't checked this though, just going on memory.